# Django - getting properly formatted decimals in forms (+crispy)?

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I have the following model:

```
class Probe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Probe name", max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.IntegerField("ordering", default=1)
    digits = models.IntegerField("trailing zeroes", null=True, blank=True, default=5)

class ProbeInst(models.Model):
    probe = models.ForeignKey(Probe, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name="probe")
    value = models.DecimalField("Value of probe", max_digits=10, decimal_places=5, null=True, blank=True)
```

I am trying to display the entry form with ModelForm and CrispyForms, which will display the necessary number of trailing zeroes according to digits field..

However when i see the actual form - i get something like this.. [image]

Basically when i enter "2" - i get "2.00000", but when i enter "81.4" - i get "81,4" for some reason...

I have tried overriding the modelform like this

```
class ProbeEntryForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'instance' in kwargs:
                step = 1 / 10 ** kwargs['instance'].probe.digits
                super(ProbeEntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                self.fields['value'].decimal_places = kwargs['instance'].probe.digits
                self.fields['value'].widget = forms.NumberInput(
                    attrs={'min': 0, 'placeholder': "Значение", 'step': step, })
                self.fields['textvalue'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

But after saving the form - i still have this float styled values displayed like "81,4"

I want to show all values with fixed number of tralining zeroes - like "81.40000" and "2.00000

Can someone please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

OK, i found the solution - adding the deciaml quantize and 'lang':'en' to attributes solved the issue!

```
class ProbeEntryForm(ModelForm):
# Переопределяем форму
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if 'instance' in kwargs:
        # Значение теста цифровое?
        if kwargs['instance'].probe.probeIsDigital:
            # Переопределяем количество десятых в полях ввода
            string = '0.' + '0' * kwargs['instance'].probe.digits
            step = 1 / 10 ** kwargs['instance'].probe.digits
            todigit = Decimal(10) ** -kwargs['instance'].probe.digits
            try:
                kwargs['instance'].value = (kwargs['instance'].value).quantize(todigit)
            except:
                print('Не введено значение цифрового теста')
            super(ProbeEntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['value'].decimal_places = kwargs['instance'].probe.digits
            self.fields['value'].widget = forms.NumberInput(
                attrs={'min': 0, 'placeholder': "Значение", 'step': step, 'lang':'en' })
            self.fields['textvalue'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        else:
            self.fields['value'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
            self.fields['textvalue'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': "Текстовое значение"})
```